# Cannot Find and Read Text File on Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, text, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

So I am creating a mobile application using Android Studio that allows the user to randomize and generate a character. I am trying to read a .txt file of the characters' names, line by line, so that I can populate an ArrayList that will hold all the names. Everything I have tried in an attempt to read the .txt file has not worked and the console always claims that the directory and file doesn't exist. I have tried using a BufferedReader, InputStreamReader, and Scanner in many ways, as shown below:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();

try {

            File file = new File(fileName);

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String curLine = br.readLine();
            while (curLine != null){
                a.add(curLine);
                curLine = br.readLine();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
```

and...

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();

try (
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                ){
            String curLine = reader.readLine();
            for (int i = 1; i != lineNum; i++){
                a.add(curLine);
                curLine = reader.readLine();
            }
            return curLine;
            }
            
        
        catch (Exception e){
           
        }
```

and...

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();

try {
            File myObj = new File(fileName);
            System.out.println(myObj.getAbsolutePath());
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                a.add(myReader.nextLine());
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

though all of them fail to work. I have tried showing the absolute path using file.getAbsolutePath() and the path is correct. I have tried putting the file parallel to the src folder, in a folder that is parallel with the src folder, in the res folder, and more. In addition, it may be important to note that I am running these lines by calling a static method in my FileIO class where I am passing in the String fileName as an argument. Is there something I'm missing? When I do this in NetBeans or Eclipse I have no issue with reading from a text file, in fact some of my old projects in NetBeans have been a template for me when I'm attempting this in Android Studio.

This is my first project with Android Studio so I am most likely doing something incorrect, so any help would be appreciated!

Note: I know that my convention for catching Exceptions is not efficient in the code provided, though when I try to catch the Exception with a FileNotFoundException, the debugger in Android Studio fails to work for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
File file = new File(filename);

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            a.add(myReader.nextLine());
         }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) { // OR CATCH AT LEAST EXCEPTION IF IT DOESNT WORK FOR FILEIOEXCEPTION
     // HERE LOG YOUR ERROR AND GIVE IT TO US
    }
```

Ensure that your "filename" is not a directory.
Test your file by logging results of some assertions:

```
System.out.println("file exists? " + file.exists());
System.out.println("file is Dir? " + file.isDirectory());
System.out.println("file can be read? " + file.canRead());
```

and give us the results.

Comment: I ran those exact lines whilst my characters.txt was parallel with my src folder. These were the results:

I/System.out: file exists? false
I/System.out: file is Dir? false
    file can be read? false
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: characters.txt (No such file or directory)

Comment: Ok, so ensure that your logged path is fully correct.
Replace your File instanciation by
    `File file = new File(path.trim())`
to ensure that the path is the one you want without spaces or anything else in the path.
Also, take the absolute path not the relative first. Once it works grab the relative one.

Comment: By path.trim(), you mean fileName.trim(), correct? If so, I tried that as well and the absolute path is exactly correct, though it still says that the file doesn't exist. I'm starting to think it is giving me the wrong error message as it may have to do with permissions.